# Using converted currency fields in formulas

Tags: multi-currency

I am using multi currencies in my org, and I can see that foreign currencies are translated into the org currency and written in brackets behind the original value. I was wondering whether this translation is available in formulas? Otherwise, how can I access it to make simple calculations?
Tia.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is:

**The converted currency value is not available in formula fields**

Now, there are some partial workarounds

1. You can use SOQL to get the converted value in the running user's currency. From the doc: `SELECT Id, convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue) FROM Account`. This might be helpful on a VF page/VF controller use case.
2. You can use a trigger to maintain a 'shadow' version of the currency field in the org currency. This will require SOQL to the `DatedConversionRate` SObject if using advanced multicurrency feature or the `CurrencyType` SObject if not using advanced multicurrency.  The downside to this approach is that if you change currency rates retroactively, you'll need to retouch all your records to get the calculation to refire